# Material-Table React: how to set action iconProps

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I've got a situation where my action icon's hover animation circle is slightly overlapping (going behind) a background item in the component above and I want to set the z Index of the icon so it stays in front.

I'm guessing that I can do this via the action iconProps.

But I can't get it to respond at all - even to color props.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
actions={[
      {
        icon: AddBox,
        iconProps: {color: 'secondary'}, 
        tooltip: 'Enrol Person',
        isFreeAction: true,
        onClick: () => {handleCreateEnrolmentDialogOpen()}
      },
    ]}
```

How would I set the z index?  I was thinking something like this, using the classes prop

```
actions={[
      {
        icon: AddBox,
        iconProps: {classes: {zIndex: 25}}, 
        tooltip: 'Enrol Person',
        isFreeAction: true,
        onClick: () => {handleCreateEnrolmentDialogOpen()}
      },
    ]}
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)